# How to make a bootstrap site non-static?

Tags: html, static

I am currently developing static websites with bootstrap. However, I would like to try create some non-static websites so the client can update simple texts by themselfs.

What kind of tool would you recommend me to do so with? I would still like to use bootstrap for structure and design.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just create a wordpress template with the bootstrap tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is using a CMS (Content Management System). There are a number of ways to approach using Bootstrap's framework with a CMS.

One simple CMS you could offer your clients would be CushyCMS: https://www.cushycms.com. CushyCMS allows you to specify editable regions within an HTML file and a client would only be able to edit those areas. This is great if you want to leave most of the website static, but allow them to change a few things in there.

If you wanted to use Wordpress, there is a Bootstrap 3 theme for Wordpress located here: http://johntransue.net/bootstrap-3-wordpress-theme/. Wordpress is a much more complicated CMS, but it has a lot of power and capability. If you take some time to master Wordpress, you can use this basic Bootstrap 3 theme plus Wordpress and develop dynamic sites using Bootstrap.